# pipenv: How to resolve dependency conflicts

Tags: python, python-packaging, pipenv

I have this dependency issue:

```
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
Could not find a version that matches futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0,>=3.2.0; python_version < "3.2"
Tried: 0.2.python3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.6, 2.2.0, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.5, 3.1.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.1
```

There is obviously an issue. The only version of package `futures` that could resolve the conflict (="3.2.0") is not available.

#### edit:

I updated the message above. now the python version also comes into the conflict.

Whats are my options here? I would like to continue to use pipenv and the Pipfile.lock

### edit

This is the graph genereated by pipenv. It took me a while to figure out that it does not work with pip v10 installed in the virtualenv. But now here it is.

```
pipenv graph

apiai==1.2.3
  - numpy [required: Any, installed: 1.14.3]
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
boto3==1.7.15
  - botocore [required: >=1.10.15,<1.11.0, installed: 1.10.15]
    - docutils [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.14]
    - jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<1.0.0, installed: 0.9.3]
    - python-dateutil [required: >=2.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.7.2]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.11.0]
  - jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<1.0.0, installed: 0.9.3]
  - s3transfer [required: >=0.1.10,<0.2.0, installed: 0.1.13]
    - botocore [required: <2.0.0,>=1.3.0, installed: 1.10.15]
      - docutils [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.14]
      - jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<1.0.0, installed: 0.9.3]
      - python-dateutil [required: >=2.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.7.2]
        - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.11.0]
celery==4.1.0
  - billiard [required: >=3.5.0.2,<3.6.0, installed: 3.5.0.3]
  - kombu [required: >=4.0.2,<5.0, installed: 4.1.0]
    - amqp [required: <3.0,>=2.1.4, installed: 2.2.2]
      - vine [required: >=1.1.3, installed: 1.1.4]
  - pytz [required: >dev, installed: 2018.4]
dialogflow==0.5.1
  - google-api-core [required: >=0.1.4,<2.0.0dev, installed: 1.2.1]
    - google-auth [required: <2.0.0dev,>=0.4.0, installed: 1.5.0]
      - cachetools [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 2.1.0]
      - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.2.1, installed: 0.2.2]
        - pyasn1 [required: <0.5.0,>=0.4.1, installed: 0.4.2]
      - rsa [required: >=3.1.4, installed: 3.4.2]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.2]
      - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.11.0]
    - googleapis-common-protos [required: <2.0dev,>=1.5.3, installed: 1.5.3]
      - protobuf [required: >=3.0.0, installed: 3.6.0]
        - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 40.0.0]
        - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.11.0]
    - protobuf [required: >=3.0.0, installed: 3.6.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 40.0.0]
      - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.11.0]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2018.4]
    - requests [required: <3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0, installed: 2.18.4]
      - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2018.4.16]
      - chardet [required: <3.1.0,>=3.0.2, installed: 3.0.4]
      - idna [required: <2.7,>=2.5, installed: 2.6]
      - urllib3 [required: <1.23,>=1.21.1, installed: 1.22]
    - setuptools [required: >=34.0.0, installed: 40.0.0]
    - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.11.0]
  - googleapis-common-protos [required: <2.0dev,>=1.5.2, installed: 1.5.3]
    - protobuf [required: >=3.0.0, installed: 3.6.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 40.0.0]
      - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.11.0]
enum-compat==0.0.2
enum34==1.1.6
eventlet==0.23.0
  - greenlet [required: >=0.3, installed: 0.4.13]
Flask-Script==2.0.6
  - Flask [required: Any, installed: 1.0.2]
    - click [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.7]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.24, installed: 0.24]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.10, installed: 2.10]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.0]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.14, installed: 0.14.1]
Flask-Scss==0.5
  - Flask [required: Any, installed: 1.0.2]
    - click [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.7]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.24, installed: 0.24]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.10, installed: 2.10]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.0]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.14, installed: 0.14.1]
  - pyScss [required: Any, installed: 1.3.5]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
Flask-SocketIO==3.0.0
  - Flask [required: >=0.9, installed: 1.0.2]
    - click [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.7]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.24, installed: 0.24]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.10, installed: 2.10]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.0]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.14, installed: 0.14.1]
  - python-socketio [required: >=1.6.1, installed: 1.9.0]
    - python-engineio [required: >=1.2.1, installed: 2.1.0]
      - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.11.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.11.0]
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
  - Flask [required: >=0.10, installed: 1.0.2]
    - click [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.7]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.24, installed: 0.24]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.10, installed: 2.10]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.0]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.14, installed: 0.14.1]
  - SQLAlchemy [required: >=0.8.0, installed: 1.2.7]
grpcio==1.13.0
  - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.11.0]
gunicorn==19.8.1
ipaddress==1.0.22
pprint==0.1
prismic==1.5.0
  - ndg-httpsclient [required: Any, installed: 0.5.0]
    - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.1, installed: 0.4.2]
    - PyOpenSSL [required: Any, installed: 17.5.0]
      - cryptography [required: >=2.1.4, installed: 2.2.2]
        - asn1crypto [required: >=0.21.0, installed: 0.24.0]
        - cffi [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.11.5]
          - pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.18]
        - idna [required: >=2.1, installed: 2.6]
        - six [required: >=1.4.1, installed: 1.11.0]
      - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.11.0]
  - pyasn1 [required: Any, installed: 0.4.2]
  - pyOpenSSL [required: Any, installed: 17.5.0]
    - cryptography [required: >=2.1.4, installed: 2.2.2]
      - asn1crypto [required: >=0.21.0, installed: 0.24.0]
      - cffi [required: >=1.7, installed: 1.11.5]
        - pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.18]
      - idna [required: >=2.1, installed: 2.6]
      - six [required: >=1.4.1, installed: 1.11.0]
    - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.11.0]
  - requests [required: >=2.7, installed: 2.18.4]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2018.4.16]
    - chardet [required: <3.1.0,>=3.0.2, installed: 3.0.4]
    - idna [required: <2.7,>=2.5, installed: 2.6]
    - urllib3 [required: <1.23,>=1.21.1, installed: 1.22]
psycopg2==2.7.4
pubnub==4.0.13
  - pycryptodomex [required: >=3.3, installed: 3.6.1]
  - requests [required: >=2.4, installed: 2.18.4]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2018.4.16]
    - chardet [required: <3.1.0,>=3.0.2, installed: 3.0.4]
    - idna [required: <2.7,>=2.5, installed: 2.6]
    - urllib3 [required: <1.23,>=1.21.1, installed: 1.22]
  - six [required: >=1.10, installed: 1.11.0]
redis==2.10.6
simplejson==3.14.0
webassets==0.12.1
```

Comment: Which pck depend on `futures` ?

Comment: I dont know. Well, that is part of the question. Where do I find that info? I am asking for a general guideline or a workflow here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the issue turned up after adding `dialogflow` to the package list.

Comment: Can you put your `pipenv graph`

Answer (score 4):

there's a long conversation about this topic [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2596) 
for some people `pipenv lock --clear` solved the problem, for me locking pylint and mypy (which caused the conflict) to the latest version, solved the problem.